# Change alpha and enabled UIButton of ClassA from ClassB in object c

Tags: objective-c, class

I change a UIButton's parameter in ClassB, but UIButton is declared in the ClassA.
How do I do see from ClassB?

Simply:

```
_closeButton.alpha = 1;
_closeButton.enabled = TRUE;
```

---

Thanks for reply!!

ok I have tried this:
in ClassB.h

> ClassA *_closeButtonController;

in ClassB.m didLoad:

> _closeButtonController = [[ClassA alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassA" bundle:nil];
>       _closeButtonController._closeButton.enabled = TRUE;
>       _closeButtonController._closeButton.alpha = 1;

I haven't error but dont' work!

---

### @Warkst in ClassA.h I have delcared @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *_closeButton;  and in ClassA.m  @synthesize _closeButton;  Use the underscore everywhere !

I have resolved with this code:
in ClassA.m

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showAndEnableCloseButton) name:@"EnableCloseButton" object:nil];
}
```

....

```
- (void)showAndEnableCloseButton
{
    _closeButton.alpha = 1;
    _closeButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

In ClassB.m
When "TouchUpInside" UIButton, close the View of ClassB and return on view of ClassA and call means NSNotificationCenter the changes in _closeButton of ClassA:

```
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"EnableCloseButton" object:self];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I hope I was of help to someone, 
Thank you all for your responses!
Good Day!

Comment: Okay, how did you declare your properties? Is it like this: property (...) UIButton * closeButton; and then in your .m file synthesize closeButton = _closebutton? Or are the underscores everywhere? How is the IBOutlet called?

Answer (score 0):

take the classA object in Class B.When you are going from class A to class B then set the classBObject.classAobj = self.

Comment: mmm I do not understand very well couldst re-explain? THNKS!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could add a method in ClassA that sets the parameters of the button and then call that method from ClassB, assuming you have a reference to your ClassA object. So:

in ClassA.h

```
- (void)showAndEnableCloseButton;
```

in ClassA.m

```
- (void)showAndEnableCloseButton{
    self._closeButton.alpha = 1;
    self._closeButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

in ClassB.h

```
ClassA * _closeButtonController;
// ...
@property (nonatomic, retain) ClassA * _closeButtonController;
```

in ClassB.m

```
@synthesize _closeButtonController;
```

Then, in your ClassA object, where you make a ClassB object:

```
// somewhere in the code from ClassA.m
ClassB * bObj = [[ClassB alloc] init];
bObj._closeButtonController = self;
// ...
```

Then, when you want to modify the button from somewhere in ClassB, you simply do this:

```
//...
[self._closeButtonController showAndEnableCloseButton];
//...
```

This should work. Hope it helps!

Comment: ok, I have a Warning "!" in a bObj._closeButtonController = self;
Incompatible pointer types assigning to "ClassA *" from "ClassB *"

Comment: First off i made a slight typo, you should change the name of the variable in ClassB.h from closeButtonController to _closeButtonController. Secondly, in the code I provided where you assign the delegate of bObj to self, I assumed you're doing that inside a ClassA object. If you're not, change "self" to any ClassA object that holds the reference to the closeButton.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this using delegation. ClassA would be the delegate of ClassB. When ClassB needs to change the UIButton in ClassA, it calls a method from ClassA (its delegate) that does this directly. Inside ClassB:

```
[self.delegate changeButtonFor:self];
```

The changeButton method in ClassA would then do what you want, directly to the UIButton.

You need to create a delegate property in ClassB, and set it to ClassA before:

```
self.delegate = _closeButtonController;
```

This is what you need to put inside your ClassB header file:

```
@class ClassB;

@protocol ButtonDelegate
- (void)changeButtonFor:(ClassB *)aClass;
@end

@interface ClassB : ...
{
    id <ButtonDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (assign) id <ButtonDelegate> delegate;
```

Don't forget to synthesize it in the implementation file:

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

Now, inside the header file of ClassA, declare that it adopts the ButtonDelegate protocol:

```
#import "ClassB.h"

@interface ClassA: ... <ButtonDelegate>
```

Then implement the changeButtonFor method in the implementation to do what you want with the butted:

```
@implementation ClassA

- (void)changeButtonFor:(ClassB *)aClass
{
    button1.alpha = 0.5;
    ...
}
```

Comment: i have an error in: '@protocol ButtonDelegate
- (void)changeButtonFor:(ClassB *)class;
@end;' Expected a type

Comment: Put this before the `@protocol` statement: `@class ClassB;`
. I have made some improvements: change the parameter name from `class` to `aClass` (both in the header and the implementation).